# How to set firebase database security rules?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

The situation is that I have a website, where at the end the user can order with filling a form, but no registration or log in is required, to be more specific, there's no possibility to register or log in. When the form is filled, with the submit button I want to validate the input with a function, and if they are valid, send it to Firebase. There are a few problems:

- there's no possibility to authenticate the user, I need to set the Firebase security rules as "open", so everybody can write and read data to the database (but it may be a good solution to set as everybody can write, but just I can read data.
- I read a bit about the config variable, and there's no good possibiity to hide that, so if somebody write a simple js program, and set the config as it's in my file, it can do whatever it want with the database

I was thought about that is it really the best solution to read the users input as order, I was thought about that maybe js can somehow send me the data to my e-mail address, but after careful research, I can't found a possibility to that. Anyways, it's sure that there's a solution to the Firebase problem. What I want is to set the only possibility to write to the database through the website, and read the data just through the Firebase Console.

Comment: That's an hot topic since the beginnings [-: Follow Dough Stevenson on Socials and look at how many questions about this topic there are out there. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQ4fb6kcCkU&index=30&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLl6zv89iLQnaaGFOHoJmVS7&linkId=58050717

Answer (score 1):

There's not much you can do if you aren't authenticating your users, I guess the best option would be to set up write rules to protect the integrity of the data being saved (so even if someone with access wrote to it they'd have to follow a structure): https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data and set read rules to nobody.

Another method may be to have an API on a backend server which makes sure all requests are coming from your website only before saving it to firebase. This way you won't have to expose your firebase config.

Comment: Upvote for the first paragraph: a public-write node is indeed quite common, and validation rules prevent invalid data (but does not prevent flooding). The second paragraph doesn't add much in terms of security: since the backend server performs the same write, all you're doing is replacing Firebase configuration data with your own (the URL of your self-made API).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @AlchemistShahed's answer, I'd recommend checking out [Firebase's anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth). This gives each user an ID, without requiring them to specify any information. It's pretty much a persistent session ID, with as little code as:

```
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously()
```

By embedding this (anonymous) user's UID into the data they write to the database, you can easily detect when a single user is flooding your queue with data.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a cloud function that would be called on form post, that function would check and sanitize data before inserting data into Firebase.  Since data insertion would be done from the server side, no config would be present client side.  Then set security on Firebase so only you can read.

You can also check those links, you might find something else in there.

Here's a link to some common use case for Firebase rules:
https://gist.github.com/codediodeio/6dbce1305b9556c2136492522e2100f6

Here's a link to Firebase security doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/